# jQuery toggle hide text first

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, show-hide

I've searched for a solution for my problem and could find a few approaches, however, none of them worked as expected. So, this is my try to understand the jQuery toggle-function. I hope you can help me!

1. The issue: I would like to hide text and make it visible after clicking on a button/link.
2. The solution: The toggle-function. Unfortunately, this shows the text first and hides it after clicking the button/link.
3. The code: So, I found this code from an older post here on stack (sorry, I can't find the author, if it's you - please text me and I'll credit you properly.)

The script:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  e.style.display = ((e.style.display!='none') ? 'none' : 'block');
}

document.getElementById('showDiv').onclick=function(){
  // Remove any element-specific value, falling back to stylesheets
  document.getElementById('element').style.display='';
};
```

In my html body-part I used the following code:

```
<a onclick="toggle_visibility('private');">
  <b>» Private Enquity / Venture Capital</b>
</a>
<div id="private">
  <p>In arcu accumsan arcu adipiscing accumsan orci ac. Felis id enim aliquet. Accumsan ac integer lobortis commodo ornare aliquet accumsan erat tempus amet porttitor. Ante commodo blandit adipiscing integer semper orci eget. Faucibus commodo adipiscing mi eu nullam accumsan morbi arcu ornare odio mi adipiscing nascetur lacus ac interdum morbi accumsan vis mi accumsan ac praesent.</p>
</div>
```

The toggle function works as described, but how can I make the text inside  hide until the link is clicked?
I'm super new to this and appreciate your help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the element hidden by default use CSS: `display: none`. You can also make the code work with an unobtrusive event handler (which is preferred over the outdated `on*` event attributes) and jQuery's `toggle()` method, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.private').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.private { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="toggle"><b>» Private Enquity / Venture Capital</b></a>
<div class="private">
  <p>In arcu accumsan arcu adipiscing accumsan orci ac. Felis id enim aliquet. Accumsan ac integer lobortis commodo ornare aliquet accumsan erat tempus amet porttitor. Ante commodo blandit adipiscing integer semper orci eget. Faucibus commodo adipiscing mi eu nullam accumsan morbi arcu ornare odio mi adipiscing nascetur lacus ac interdum morbi accumsan vis mi accumsan ac praesent.</p>
</div>
```

Note that I changed the `id` to a `class` as this mechanism is often repeated throughout a page, which would lead to repeated `id` attribute which is invalid HTML.

Comment: isn't it good practice to attach event to id instead of class?
Because, if developer used same class '.toogle' somewhere else, click event will be attached to it.

Comment: @TavishAggarwal no, not at all. They have completely separate use cases. In the case you mention then you should make the selector more accurate, eg. `$('#container .parent a.toggle').click(...`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this Help!

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
     //e.style.display = ((e.style.display!='none') ? 'none' : 'block');
    }
               
    document.getElementById('showDiv').onclick=function(){
      // Remove any element-specific value, falling back to stylesheets
      $('#element').toggleClass('display');
      // $('#element2').toggleClass('display');
    };
```

```css
.display {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('private');">
      <b id="showDiv">» Private Enquity / Venture Capital</b>
</a>

<p id="element" class="display">In arcu accumsan arcu adipiscing accumsan orci ac. Felis id enim aliquet. Accumsan ac integer lobortis commodo ornare aliquet accumsan erat tempus amet porttitor. Ante commodo blandit adipiscing integer semper orci eget. Faucibus commodo adipiscing mi eu nullam accumsan morbi arcu ornare odio mi adipiscing nascetur lacus ac interdum morbi accumsan vis mi accumsan ac praesent.</p>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your fast answer!
This works if I use just one element, but I have more than that on my page.
How can I make it work if I have other texts that I want to hide as well?

Comment: @ygmrydgn l have edited my answer, you can add line  $('#element2').toggleClass('display'); where #element2 are other div ids that you want to hide.

Comment: I used the above solution from rory-mccrossan, that seems to be an easy fix for my solution. thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a").click(function(){
$("#private").toggle();
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">
  <b>» Private Enquity / Venture Capital</b>
</a>
<div id="private">
  <p>In arcu accumsan arcu adipiscing accumsan orci ac. Felis id enim aliquet. Accumsan ac integer lobortis commodo ornare aliquet accumsan erat tempus amet porttitor. Ante commodo blandit adipiscing integer semper orci eget. Faucibus commodo adipiscing mi eu nullam accumsan morbi arcu ornare odio mi adipiscing nascetur lacus ac interdum morbi accumsan vis mi accumsan ac praesent.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this works like my code example did. It shows the text first and hides after a click. I need it reversed.